# fsockopen() unable to connect to ssl

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, smtp

Before hosting my site, the email was working fine but after hosting, it started giving warnings:

```
fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://mail.mysite.example: 25 (connection refused)in /home/mysite/public_html/beta/sys/libraries/Email.php on line 2061
```

Here's my setting

```
username: support@mysite.com
Password: Use the email account's password
Incoming server: mail.mysite.example
                 IMAP Port: 993  POP3 Port:995

Outgoing Server: mail.mysite.example
                 SMTP Port: 465
```

Here's my code:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'mail.mysite.example',
    'smtp_port' => 25,
    'smtp_user' => 'support@mysite',
    'smtp_pass' => '####',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your SMTP port doesn't match.

In your settings it is specified as `SMTP Port: 465`, in your code it is set to `'smtp_port' => 25`. Your code needs to be :
`'smtp_port' => 465`

Comment: This is the right answer. The reason it will fail is that SMTP on port 465 is an *implicit* TLS service (known as 'SMTPS'), and it expects you to be talking TLS from the very beginning. That would interfere with normal unencrypted SMTP service on port 25, so you can't use it there. This is not the case with 'SMTP+STARTTLS', which is an *explicit* TLS service typically run on port 587, but (unlike SMTPS) can also coexist on port 25 with "regular" SMTP.